# sql performance in accounting software invoice list

Tags: sql-server, timeout, accounting

I have database that include FinancialYears in each table for Invoices, the problem is that when I call query to show the Invoice list for example for 2024 and then change the app to 2023 to get query on last year it gives me a time out error
this is my invoice header table schema

```
CREATE TABLE [Sales].[InvoiceHeader](
    [InvoiceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceNumber1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [OnlineInvoiceFlag] [bit] NULL,
    [RecordType] [smallint] NULL,
    [InvoiceKindFK] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StoreFK] [int] NULL,
    [IsOther] [bit] NULL,
    [OtherName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [OtherNationalNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AccountGroupFK] [int] NULL,
    [AccountFK] [int] NULL,
    [PaymentTermFK] [int] NULL,
    [DeliverAddress] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [Date] [char](10) NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [SubTotal] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Reduction] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Extra] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Discount] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [ProjectFK] [int] NULL,
    [CostCenterFK] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [MarketerAccountFK] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MarketingCost] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [DriverAccountFK] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DriverWages] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [SettelmentDate] [char](10) NULL,
    [DueDate] [char](10) NULL,
    [PrintCount] [tinyint] NULL,
    [InvoiceFK] [int] NULL,
    [LetterFK] [int] NULL,
    [FinancialPeriodFK] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyInfoFK] [tinyint] NULL,
    [OldSysDoc] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InvoiceHeader] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FinancialPeriodFK] ASC,
    [InvoiceKindFK] ASC,
    [InvoiceID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Sales].[InvoiceHeader] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_InvoiceHeader_Time]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Time]
GO
```

and following is my detail invoice table schema

```
CREATE TABLE [Sales].[InvoiceDetail](
    [InvoiceFK] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceDetailID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceNumberFK] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceKindFK] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RecordType] [smallint] NULL,
    [ItemDescription] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [Date] [char](10) NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [StoreFK] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductFK] [int] NULL,
    [OrderQty] [float] NULL,
    [UnitPrice] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [BackPrice] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [UnitPriceDiscountPercent] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [DiscountAmount] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [UnitPriceVatPercent] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [VatAmount] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [UnitPriceTaxPercent] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [TaxAmount] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [TransportCost] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [LineTotal] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [WayBillNumber] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ContractNumber] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [VehicleNo] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [DeliverFK] [int] NULL,
    [NTSW] [nvarchar](512) NULL,
    [FinancialPeriodFK] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyInfoFK] [tinyint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InvoiceDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FinancialPeriodFK] ASC,
    [InvoiceKindFK] ASC,
    [InvoiceDetailID] ASC,
    [InvoiceFK] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Sales].[InvoiceDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_InvoiceDetail_Time]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Time]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Sales].[InvoiceDetail]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_InvoiceDetail_InvoiceHeader] FOREIGN KEY([FinancialPeriodFK], [InvoiceKindFK], [InvoiceFK])
REFERENCES [Sales].[InvoiceHeader] ([FinancialPeriodFK], [InvoiceKindFK], [InvoiceID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Sales].[InvoiceDetail] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_InvoiceDetail_InvoiceHeader]
GO
```

Note: in 2023 I have 6600 invoice inserted in my table.
and in total from 2018 to 2024 I have 106000 record inserted for my invoices.
following is my query :

```sql
SELECT M.InvoiceID,
       M.InvoiceNumber,
       M.InvoiceNumber1,
       M.IsOther,
       M.OtherName,
       M.OtherNationalNo,
       M.Date,
       (SUM(ISNULL(D.LineTotal, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(M.Extra, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(M.Reduction, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(D.DiscountAmount, 0))) AS SumTotal,
       (SUM(ISNULL(D.DiscountAmount, 0))) AS Discount,
       (SUM(ISNULL(D.VatAmount, 0))) AS Vat,
       (SUM(ISNULL(D.TaxAmount, 0))) AS Tax,
       (SUM(ISNULL(D.LineTotal, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(D.VatAmount, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(D.TaxAmount, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(M.Extra, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(M.Reduction, 0))) AS TotalNet,
       M.OnlineInvoiceFlag,
       M.RecordType,
       M.InvoiceKindFK,
       M.StoreFK,
       M.AccountFK,
       M.PaymentTermFK,
       M.DeliverAddress,
       (SELECT MAX(DocumentFK)
        FROM Accounting.DocumentDetail
        WHERE ItemFK = @Item + CAST(M.InvoiceNumber AS nvarchar(10))
          AND documenttypeid = @DocumentTypeFK
          AND financialPeriodFK = @FinancialPeriodFK) AS DocumentNumber,
       M.Time,
       M.Description,
       M.SubTotal,
       M.Reduction,
       M.Extra,
       M.ProjectFK,
       M.CostCenterFK,
       M.MarketerAccountFK,
       M.MarketingCost,
       M.DriverAccountFK,
       M.DriverWages,
       M.SettelmentDate,
       M.DueDate,
       M.FinancialPeriodFK,
       M.CompanyInfoFK,
       M.PrintCount,
       M.LetterFK,
       M.InvoiceFK,
       dbo.getname(M.AccountFK, M.AccountGroupFK, M.FinancialPeriodFK) AS AccountTopic,
       AccountGroupFK,
       SUM(Banking.ReceivedCash.Price) AS ReceivedCash,
       SUM(Banking.ReceivedCheque.Price) AS ReceivedCheque
FROM Sales.InvoiceHeader M
    LEFT JOIN Sales.InvoiceDetail D ON M.InvoiceID = D.InvoiceFK
                                   AND M.InvoiceKindFK = D.InvoiceKindFK
                                   AND D.FinancialPeriodFK = M.FinancialPeriodFK
    LEFT JOIN Banking.ReceivedCash ON M.InvoiceNumber = Banking.ReceivedCash.SalesInvoiceHeaderFK
                                  AND Banking.ReceivedCash.FinancialPeriodFK = M.FinancialPeriodFK
    LEFT JOIN Banking.ReceivedCheque ON M.InvoiceNumber = Banking.ReceivedCheque.SalesInvoiceHeaderFK
                                    AND Banking.ReceivedCheque.FinancialPeriodFK = M.FinancialPeriodFK
WHERE ( (M.InvoiceKindFK = @InvoiceKindFK)
    AND (M.FinancialPeriodFK = @FinancialPeriodFK))
GROUP BY M.InvoiceID,
         M.InvoiceNumber,
         M.InvoiceNumber1,
         M.IsOther,
         M.OtherName,
         M.OtherNationalNo,
         M.Date,
         M.OnlineInvoiceFlag,
         M.RecordType,
         M.InvoiceKindFK,
         M.InvoiceNumber,
         M.StoreFK,
         M.AccountFK,
         M.PaymentTermFK,
         M.DeliverAddress,
         M.Time,
         M.Description,
         M.SubTotal,
         M.Reduction,
         M.Extra,
         M.ProjectFK,
         M.CostCenterFK,
         M.MarketerAccountFK,
         M.MarketingCost,
         M.DriverAccountFK,
         M.DriverWages,
         M.SettelmentDate,
         M.DueDate,
         M.FinancialPeriodFK,
         M.OldSysDoc,
         M.CompanyInfoFK,
         M.PrintCount,
         M.LetterFK,
         M.InvoiceFK,
         M.AccountGroupFK
ORDER BY M.StoreFK,
         M.InvoiceNumber;
```

Comment: I think you will have more luck if you provide the indexes in a text form as well as the query plan generated (see https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Images of the table designer isn't helpful. Post the DDL if it's important.

Comment: @ThomA thank you I  already added that to my post

Comment: Your keys look good, can the problem be in: a) dbo.getname, a scalar function usually kills performance b) Banking.ReceivedCash table, It doesn't show any definition so it's hard to say how bad that table affects things c) you can try adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) to your query after the Order By to see if it helps d) is @InvoiceKindFK of matching type as InvoiceKindFK etc? Some of those were TINYINT for example

Comment: The `GROUP BY` has a smell to it; you're grouping by 30+ columns. I suspect pre-aggregation would be better solution here.

Comment: Also that subquery could be a contender. You don't qualify your column names (a fatal mistake) and it's not SARGable with the clause `ItemFK = @Item + CAST(M.InvoiceNumber AS nvarchar(10))`. Do you not have an actual column that can be `JOIN`ed on?

Comment: As an FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](//wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated) and should be avoided. You're far better off aliasing your objects `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable. Oddly, you alias in some places (`Sales.InvoiceDetail D ON M.InvoiceID = D.InvoiceFK` as an example), but then don't in others: `Banking.ReceivedCash ON M.InvoiceNumber = Banking.ReceivedCash.SalesInvoiceHeaderFK`

Comment: Also you probably aren't even getting correct results. If more than one of those joins is not unique (returning multiple per outer row) then you get a cartesian product between the joins. You really should use pre-aggregation in subqueries or CTEs.

Comment: @Charlieface probably, but it looks better on the balance sheet

Comment: CONSTRAINT [FK_InvoiceDetail_InvoiceHeader] FOREIGN KEY([FinancialPeriodFK], [InvoiceKindFK], [InvoiceFK]) REFERENCES [Sales].[InvoiceHeader] ([FinancialPeriodFK], [InvoiceKindFK], [InvoiceID])  maybe reduced to CONSTRAINT [FK_InvoiceDetail_InvoiceHeader] FOREIGN KEY( [InvoiceFK]) REFERENCES [Sales].[InvoiceHeader] ( [InvoiceID])

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your `GROUP BY` is grouping the entirety of each `InvoiceHeader` row, while the other table references are only used to calculate sums for details and payments. In that case, I believe that is would be simpler to select directly from `InvoiceHeader` only at the top level and use `CROSS APPLY` subqueries to calculate the various sums.

The other thing I see, and this is a *big red flag*, is that your posted query appears to have **multiple independent one-to-many joins**. This will almost never yield the correct result. If an invoice had three details, two cash payments and two cheque payments, the details would be overstated by a factor of 4 and payments would each be overstated by a factor of 6. The fix is to isolate each one-to-many relationship into a separate `CROSS APPLY` and calculate the totals of each independently.

The `DocumentNumber` can also (optionally) be moved to a `CROSS APPLY`, solely for the purpose of reducing clutter in the main select list.

These `CROSS APPLY` results can then be referenced in the top level select list.

The updated query would be something like:

```
SELECT M.InvoiceID,
       M.InvoiceNumber,
       M.InvoiceNumber1,
       M.IsOther,
       M.OtherName,
       M.OtherNationalNo,
       M.Date,
       DSUM.LineTotal + DSUM.Extra - DSUM.Reduction + DSUM.Discount AS SumTotal,
       DSUM.Discount,
       DSUM.Vat,
       DSUM.Tax,
       DSUM.LineTotal - DSUM.Vat - DSUM.Tax - DSUM.Extra - DSUM.Reduction AS TotalNet,
       M.OnlineInvoiceFlag,
       M.RecordType,
       M.InvoiceKindFK,
       M.StoreFK,
       M.AccountFK,
       M.PaymentTermFK,
       M.DeliverAddress,
       DN.DocumentNumber,
       M.Time,
       M.Description,
       M.SubTotal,
       M.Reduction,
       M.Extra,
       M.ProjectFK,
       M.CostCenterFK,
       M.MarketerAccountFK,
       M.MarketingCost,
       M.DriverAccountFK,
       M.DriverWages,
       M.SettelmentDate,
       M.DueDate,
       M.FinancialPeriodFK,
       M.CompanyInfoFK,
       M.PrintCount,
       M.LetterFK,
       M.InvoiceFK,
       dbo.getname(M.AccountFK, M.AccountGroupFK, M.FinancialPeriodFK) AS AccountTopic,
       M.AccountGroupFK,
       RCSUM.ReceivedCash,
       RQSUM.ReceivedCheque
FROM Sales.InvoiceHeader M
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(D.LineTotal, 0)), 0) AS LineTotal,
        ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(M.Extra, 0)), 0) AS Extra,
        ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(M.Reduction, 0)), 0) AS Reduction,
        ISNULL((SUM(ISNULL(D.DiscountAmount, 0)), 0) AS Discount,
        ISNULL((SUM(ISNULL(D.VatAmount, 0)), 0) AS Vat,
        ISNULL((SUM(ISNULL(D.TaxAmount, 0)), 0) AS Tax
    FROM Sales.InvoiceDetail D
    WHERE D.InvoiceFK = M.InvoiceID
    AND D.InvoiceKindFK = M.InvoiceKindFK
    AND D.FinancialPeriodFK = M.FinancialPeriodFK
) DSUM
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ISNULL(SUM(RC.Price), 0) AS ReceivedCash
    FROM Banking.ReceivedCash RC
    WHERE RC.SalesInvoiceHeaderFK = M.InvoiceNumber
    AND RC.FinancialPeriodFK = M.FinancialPeriodFK
) RCSUM
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Banking.ReceivedCheque.Price), 0) AS ReceivedCheque
    FROM Banking.ReceivedCheque RQ
    WHERE RQ.SalesInvoiceHeaderFK = M.InvoiceNumber
    AND RQ.FinancialPeriodFK = M.FinancialPeriodFK
) RQSUM
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(DocumentFK) AS DocumentNumber
    FROM Accounting.DocumentDetail DD
    WHERE DD.ItemFK = @Item + CAST(M.InvoiceNumber AS nvarchar(10))
    AND DD.documenttypeid = @DocumentTypeFK
    AND DD.financialPeriodFK = @FinancialPeriodFK
) DN
WHERE ( (M.InvoiceKindFK = @InvoiceKindFK)
    AND (M.FinancialPeriodFK = @FinancialPeriodFK))
ORDER BY M.StoreFK,
         M.InvoiceNumber;
```

A `CROSS APPLY` is like an `INNER JOIN` to a subselect. For each usage above, the aggregate functions will always produce a single scalar result, so each should produce exactly one row. (If that was not the case, an `OUTER APPLY` would have been appropriate - equivalent to a `LEFT JOIN` to a subselect.)

I wrapped the `SUM()`s up in additional `ISNULL()` functions to ensure a zero result if no matching rows were found. The inner `ISNULL()` function references could be eliminated if you don't mind the "Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation" warnings.

As *siggemannen* already pointed out in an earlier comment, the `dbo.getname()` function call may be significantly impacting performance. I suggest testing your query both with and without this function call. If significantly different, review the function to see if its performance can be improved or if its logic can be merged into the above query. Another option might be to add `AccountTopic` as a persistent computed column  in the `InvoiceHeader` table.

I presume that:

- Every invoice should have at least one and perhaps multiple detail rows.
- Every invoice may have zero, one, or multiple cash payment rows.
- Every invoice may have zero, one, or multiple cheque payment rows.

Be sure to test the final query using all combinations of the above conditions, carefully checking that the calculated sums are correct.

Also, check your `InvoiceDetail` join conditions. The referenced columns are not the same as defined in your `FK_InvoiceDetail_InvoiceHeader` foreign key constraint. (The other three table definitions were not posted, but might also be worth a review.)