# Join 4 tables in calculate their values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables that needs to be joined, 3 of them are needed to be calculated and their values to be provided in the forth one. and in the joins there are 2 fields that is important and needed to be grouped by.

First Table:

```
SELECT  customerId, baseCurrencyId, totalOldDebt, totalRecoveredDebt, totalPaidDebt
FROM    ViewCustomerDebt
```

Result from the first query:

| customerId | baseCurrencyId | totalOldDebt | totalRecoveredDebt | totalPaidDebt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2000 | 950 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 | 100 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 300 | 500 | 1000 |

Second table:

```
SELECT  customerId ,paymentTypeId ,baseCurrencyId ,subTotalPrice ,totalPrice ,totalCost
FROM    ViewCustomerSell
```

Result from selcond query:

| customerId | paymentTypeId | baseCurrencyId | subTotalPrice | totalPrice | totalCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 5300 | 5300 | 5008 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 292.5 | 287.5 | 181 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 20638.5 | 20538.5 | 492 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 10 | 10 | 1000 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 174.5 | 174.5 | 160.5 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 1172 | 1172 | 6016 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 661 | 661 | 626 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 144 | 144 | 132.25 |

Third query:

```sql
SELECT  customerId ,paymentTypeId ,baseCurrencyId ,totalPrice ,totalCost
FROM    ViewCustomerPurchase
```

Result from third query:

| customerId | paymentTypeId | baseCurrencyId | totalPrice | totalCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 91610 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 115.5 | 0 |

The `paymentTypeId` in `ViewCustomerSell` and `ViewCustomerDebt` is either `1` or `2`.
And then I want to select from `Customer` table and get these columns:

```
customerId
baseCurrencyId,
totalPaidSellPrice (ViewCustomerSell.totalPrice where paymentTypeId = 1),
totalDebtSellPrice (ViewCustomerSell.totalPrice where paymentTypeId = 2),
totalSellDebt ((ViewCustomerSell.totalPrice where paymentTypeId = 2) + ViewCustomerDebt.totalOldDebt - ViewCustomerDebt.totalRecoveredDebt),
totalPaidPurchasePrice (ViewCustomerPurchase.totalPrice where paymentTypeId = 1),
totalDebtPurchasePrice (ViewCustomerPurchase.totalPrice where paymentTypeId = 2),
totalPurchaseDebt ((ViewCustomerPurchase.totalPrice where paymentTypeId = 2) - ViewCustomerDebt.totalPaidDebt),
totalDebtExchange (totalSellDebt - totalPurchaseDebt)
```

But I want them all to be grouped by `customerId` and `baseCurrencyId`.

Here is my expected result:

| customerId | baseCurrencyId | totalPaidSellPrice | totalDebtSellPrice | totalSellDebt | totalPaidPurchasePrice | totalDebtPurchasePrice | totalPurchaseDebt | totalDebtExchange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 287.5 | 20538.5 | 21588.5 | 0 | 91610 | 91610 | -70021.5 |
| 4 | 1 | 661 | 144 | 134 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 134 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 10 | -190 | 0 | 0 | -1000 | -1190 |
| 3 | 1 | 174.5 | 1172 | 1172 | 0 | 115.5 | 115.5 | 1056.5 |
| 1 | 1 | 5300 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

and so on.

I tried this code but it did not work as I wanted:

```sql
SELECT C.id as customerId,
    COALESCE (VCD.baseCurrencyId, VCSP.baseCurrencyId, VCSD.baseCurrencyId, VCPP.baseCurrencyId, VCPD.baseCurrencyId) 
        AS baseCurrencyId,
    VCSP.totalPrice as totalPaidSellPrice,
    VCSD.totalPrice as totalDebtSellPrice,
    VCSD.totalPrice + VCD.totalOldDebt - VCD.totalRecoveredDebt as totalSellDebt,
    VCPP.totalPrice as totalPaidPurchasePrice,
    VCPD.totalPrice as totalDebtPurchasePrice,
    VCPD.totalPrice - VCD.totalPaidDebt as totalPurchaseDebt,
    (VCSD.totalPrice + VCD.totalOldDebt - VCD.totalRecoveredDebt) -
        (VCPD.totalPrice - VCD.totalPaidDebt) as totalExchange
from ViewCustomerDebt as VCD
Full outer join ViewCustomerSell as VCSP on VCD.customerId = VCSP.customerId and 
    VCD.baseCurrencyId = VCSP.baseCurrencyId and VCSP.paymentTypeId = 1
Full outer join ViewCustomerSell as VCSD on VCD.customerId = VCSD.customerId 
    and VCD.baseCurrencyId = VCSD.baseCurrencyId and VCSD.paymentTypeId = 2
Full outer join ViewCustomerPurchase as VCPP on VCD.customerId = VCPP.customerId and 
    VCD.baseCurrencyId = VCPP.baseCurrencyId and VCPP.paymentTypeId = 1
Full outer join ViewCustomerPurchase as VCPD on VCD.customerId = VCPD.customerId 
    and VCD.baseCurrencyId = VCPD.baseCurrencyId and VCPD.paymentTypeId = 2
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer AS C ON C.id = 
        COALESCE (VCD.customerId, VCSP.customerId, VCSD.customerId, VCPP.customerId, VCPD.customerId)
```

Here is a db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/uGO8az0s

Comment: This appears to be a variation on [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78233952/). It is also surprisingly similar to another question I [answered earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78230657/78232207#78232207). You have what appear to be multiple one-to-many relationships between `ViewCustomerDebt` and `ViewCustomerSell` and `ViewCustomerPurchase`, so performing `FULL OUTER JOIN`s is going to cause data duplication and overstated results. As described in my earlier answer, the solution is to use `CROSS APPLY`s to calculate the required aggregated values.

Comment: @TN yes it is close to that in fact the `ViewCustomerDebt` is it from that question, can you help me with the full query becase i couldn't find the right answer?

Comment: You have `customerId = 1` with `baseCurrencyId = 1`. Where does this comes from ? in `ViewCustomerDebt` it is `customerId = 1` with `baseCurrencyId = 2`

Comment: if you talk about the expected result, it is not complete and there are so many rows missing, it is just to clarify how it should look and i only calculated a few rows in it

Comment: It is important that the expected result is complete for the provided sample data. Else it is going to confuse the reader

Comment: @Squirrel i have updated the expected result and i believe it is complete now

Comment: How does `customerId = 1` with `baseCurrencyId = 1` comes from in your expected result when in `ViewCustomerDebt`, `customerId = 1`  only have `baseCurrencyId 2`

Comment: the goal here it to calculate the values based on customer not debts, he have no records here but he does in the others

Comment: @Squirrel i have got this query https://dbfiddle.uk/XWd9103A can you please check it out to see if i am missing something?

Comment: @TN i have got this query https://dbfiddle.uk/XWd9103A can you please check it out to see if i am missing something?

Comment: @Rawand if its returning you the results you wish, how could you have missed anything?

Comment: @DaleK what i meant was if you have a better way to do it

Comment: How do you define better? Faster? Easier to read? Other?

Comment: @Rawand - Do you really need `FULL OUTER JOIN`s? Will there be cases where a Purchase or Debt row exists with no corresponding Sell? If not, you can just use a `LEFT JOIN`. It such cases can exist, you need to be careful with your join conditions. A Debt might match a Purchase but not a Sell, a Sell but not a Purchase, Debt might match both, or a Debt might match neither. To properly handle these cases, you need to use `COALESCE()` in the join conditions to handle the various match cases, as @ThorstenKettner has demonstrated in their answer.

Comment: @TN Yes there will be cases where there are only debts and no sell or purchase, or a debt and a purchase or sell and debt

Comment: @DaleK better performance is the main goal for me, but if not better performance. Then can what i did be achieved in less code?

Answer (score 1):

You want a result with one row per customerId and baseCurrencyId. So, for all tables where there is no unique constraint on these two columns, you'll have to aggregate the table first in order to produce one row per customerId and baseCurrencyId. Once you are there you can join the results on these two columns. In the following query I assume that the aggregation is necessary for all your views.

```
WITH
  debt AS
  (
    SELECT 
      customerid,
      basecurrencyid,
      SUM(totalolddebt) AS old,
      SUM(totalrecovereddebt) AS recovered,
      SUM(totalpaiddebt) AS paid
    FROM viewcustomerdebt
    GROUP BY customerid, basecurrencyid
  ),
  sell AS
  (
    SELECT
      customerid,
      basecurrencyid,
      SUM(CASE WHEN paymenttypeid = 1 THEN totalprice END) AS price_type1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN paymenttypeid = 2 THEN totalprice END) AS price_type2
    FROM viewcustomersell
    GROUP BY customerid, basecurrencyid
  ),
  purchase AS
  (
    SELECT
      customerid,
      basecurrencyid,
      SUM(CASE WHEN paymenttypeid = 1 THEN totalprice END) AS price_type1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN paymenttypeid = 2 THEN totalprice END) AS price_type2
    FROM viewcustomerpurchase
    GROUP BY customerid, basecurrencyid
  )
SELECT
  COALESCE(debt.customerid, sell.customerid, purchase.customerid) AS customerid,
  COALESCE(debt.basecurrencyid, sell.basecurrencyid, purchase.basecurrencyid) AS basecurrencyid,
  COALESCE(sell.price_type1, 0) AS total_paid_sell_price,
  COALESCE(sell.price_type2, 0) AS total_debt_sell_price,
  COALESCE(sell.price_type2, 0) + COALESCE(debt.old, 0) - COALESCE(debt.recovered, 0) AS total_sell_debt,
  COALESCE(purchase.price_type1, 0) AS total_paid_purchase_price,
  COALESCE(purchase.price_type2, 0) AS total_debt_purchase_price,
  COALESCE(purchase.price_type2, 0) - COALESCE(debt.paid, 0) AS total_purchase_debt,
  (COALESCE(sell.price_type2, 0) + COALESCE(debt.old, 0) - COALESCE(debt.recovered, 0)) - (COALESCE(purchase.price_type2, 0) - COALESCE(debt.paid, 0)) AS total_debt_exchange
FROM debt
FULL OUTER JOIN sell ON sell.customerid = debt.customerid
                    AND sell.basecurrencyid = debt.basecurrencyid
FULL OUTER JOIN purchase ON purchase.customerid = COALESCE(debt.customerid, sell.customerid)
                        AND purchase.basecurrencyid = COALESCE(debt.basecurrencyid, sell.basecurrencyid)
ORDER BY
  COALESCE(debt.customerid, sell.customerid, purchase.customerid),
  COALESCE(debt.basecurrencyid, sell.basecurrencyid, purchase.basecurrencyid);
```

If SQL Server were standard SQL compliant and supported the `USING` clause, the joins would look like this:

```
FROM debt
FULL OUTER JOIN sell USING (customerid, basecurrencyid)
FULL OUTER JOIN purchase USING (customerid, basecurrencyid)
```

and the clumsy

```
COALESCE(debt.customerid, sell.customerid, purchase.customerid)
COALESCE(debt.basecurrencyid, sell.basecurrencyid, purchase.basecurrencyid)
```

would become mere

```
customerid
basecurrencyid
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/xtEwUV7h

Comment: Thank you for your response, after trying for a few hours i got a query simillar to yours, here it is https://dbfiddle.uk/mqd-04Da but as i see you are much better than me in SQL and i would really appreciate if you could check it out and let me know if i missed anything

Comment: On a quick glance: You have `FROM s FULL JOIN p ON s.xxx = p.xxx FULL JOIN vcd ON s.xxx = vcd.xxx;`. So if you have a row in p, but no matching row in s, then your vcd join will not work, because you only look at s where all values are null. This is easy with `USING`, but with `ON` you must make sure that you match vcd on either s or p. I am using `COALESCE` for this in my query. Another option would be `OR`.

Comment: totalDebtExchange (totalSellDebt - totalPurchaseDebt): (-190) - (-1000) = +810. You have -1190 instead, because your calculation lacks a pair of parentheses.

Comment: Thank you, i will lock back at it but it worked as expected and the testing team has no complaints as it is in testing phase for now. If there was any i will try to recreate it usin your method or i may even add comment asking fro help from you, but thanks for now

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out by first differentiating the paymentTypeId for sell and purchase, then joining them all together and calculating the values, here is my result:

```sql
WITH SellTotals AS (
    SELECT 
        customerId,
        baseCurrencyId,
        SUM(CASE WHEN paymentTypeId = 1 THEN totalPrice ELSE 0 END) AS totalPaidSellPrice,
        SUM(CASE WHEN paymentTypeId = 2 THEN totalPrice ELSE 0 END) AS totalDebtSellPrice
    FROM 
        ViewCustomerSell
    GROUP BY 
        customerId, baseCurrencyId
),
PurchaseTotals AS (
    SELECT 
        customerId,
        baseCurrencyId,
        SUM(CASE WHEN paymentTypeId = 1 THEN totalPrice ELSE 0 END) AS totalPaidPurchasePrice,
        SUM(CASE WHEN paymentTypeId = 2 THEN totalPrice ELSE 0 END) AS totalDebtPurchasePrice
    FROM 
        ViewCustomerPurchase
    GROUP BY 
        customerId, baseCurrencyId
),
  DebtTotals AS (
    SELECT 
        customerId,
        baseCurrencyId,
        SUM(totalOldDebt) AS totalOldDebt,
        SUM(totalRecoveredDebt) AS totalRecoveredDebt,
        SUM(totalPaidDebt) AS totalPaidDebt
    FROM 
        ViewCustomerDebt
    GROUP BY 
        customerId, baseCurrencyId
)
SELECT
  NEWID() AS uid,
  COALESCE(S.customerId, P.customerId, VCD.customerId) AS customerId,
  COALESCE(
    S.baseCurrencyId,
    P.baseCurrencyId,
    VCD.baseCurrencyId
  ) AS baseCurrencyId,
  COALESCE(S.totalPaidSellPrice, 0) AS totalPaidSellPrice,
  COALESCE(S.totalDebtSellPrice, 0) AS totalDebtSellPrice,
  COALESCE(S.totalDebtSellPrice, 0) + COALESCE(VCD.totalOldDebt, 0) - COALESCE(VCD.totalRecoveredDebt, 0) AS totalSellDebt,
  COALESCE(P.totalPaidPurchasePrice, 0) AS totalPaidPurchasePrice,
  COALESCE(P.totalDebtPurchasePrice, 0) AS totalDebtPurchasePrice,
  COALESCE(P.totalDebtPurchasePrice, 0) - COALESCE(VCD.totalPaidDebt, 0) AS totalPurchaseDebt,
  COALESCE(S.totalPaidSellPrice, 0) - COALESCE(P.totalPaidPurchasePrice, 0) AS totalPaidExchange,
  COALESCE(S.totalDebtSellPrice, 0) + COALESCE(VCD.totalOldDebt, 0) - COALESCE(VCD.totalRecoveredDebt, 0) - COALESCE(P.totalDebtPurchasePrice, 0) - COALESCE(VCD.totalPaidDebt, 0) AS totalDebtExchange
FROM
  SellTotals AS S FULL
  JOIN PurchaseTotals AS P ON S.customerId = P.customerId
  AND S.baseCurrencyId = P.baseCurrencyId FULL
  JOIN DebtTotals AS VCD ON S.customerId = VCD.customerId
  AND S.baseCurrencyId = VCD.baseCurrencyId;
```

Comment: *(It's an odd place to put a line break between `FULL` and `JOIN`. Are you using an auto-formatter? Seems like it can't decide between operators at end of prior line or operators at start of new line and chooses the middle ground. Grin.)*

Comment: You are probably going to need to use `COALESCE()` for the second `FULL OUTER JOIN` conditions.  See @ThorstenKettner's answer.